# jQuery .val() on option in ie8?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, html-select

I am dynamically adding a new option to a select list, and all I want to do is select it, as it comes from user input.  Odds are, they want the new option they just added.

```
var msg = "an ajax return from a modal input that works";
$("#myselect").append( $('<option></option>').val(msg).html(msg) );
```

The item does get added to the select, but it is not selected.

I only have ie8 to test with, and comply with, on internet networks...

is this a browser bug, or is my code wrong?

my understanding was that `.val()` should select it.

Comment: have you tried calling `val()` on the `select` and not on the option element after adding the `option`? EDIT: what adaneo suggested.

Comment: Thanks Florian, that looks to be the key issue i missed here.  But i still don't have a working solution.

Comment: Ok, Now i do.   
$("#myselect").append( $('<option></option>').val(msg).html(msg)).val(msg);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

changing the options value doesn't set the select to that value, you have to set the selects value to do that

```
var msg = "an ajax return from a modal input that works";

$("#myselect").append( $('<option>' + msg + '</option>') ).val(msg);
```

Or you can set the selected property, but you would have to make sure no other options are selected :

```
var option = $('<option />', {text:msg, selected:'selected'});
$("#myselect").find('option').prop('selected', false).end().append( option );
```

Comment: Using first method, this is closer, but doesn't seem to work.   It adds the option, and then selects a blank after the newly created option.   I see the flaw in that adding the .val(msg) was to the option, not the select now though.

Comment: using dom explorer, this is why... (i entered 77)
<OPTION value="77">77</OPTION><OPTION value="77"></OPTION

it makes two options, but one has no display text.

Comment: Then the code runs twice for some other reason, or you're looping over something that has the same value twice ?

Comment: Correction, this DOES work.   I had another snippit of bad code in there. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Your code is wrong.

You create the options, but you never select it.

After appending the options, you can call `.val()` on the select element to set the selected option.

Calling `.val()` on the option sets the option's *value* – the value that the select will have when that option is selected.

Comment: I see the flaw in that adding the .val(msg) was to the option, not the select.

Answer (score 0):

You can also `$("#myselect:last")` to select the last option.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
var msg = "an ajax return from a modal input that works";
$("#myselect").append('<option value="'+msg+'" selected="selected">'+msg+'</option>');
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hieuh25/aBBRy/1/